# Why value of y and +y is same in scala REPL in below scenario

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

```
scala> val y=20
val y: Int = 20

scala> y
val res0: Int = 20

scala> +y
val res1: Int = 20
```

Comment: Hi Prakhar! Welcome to stackoverflow :) What you think is the right value of `+y`? Please try to give us more details.

Comment: Well I am beginner to scala . So i want to understand why scala is treating both same. According to me it should throw error something like not found: value +y

Comment: What do you think it should do with `-y`? Why should `+y` be any different?

Comment: To be fair, under the hood scala accepts the unary prefix `+` only for the objects that have defined the method `unary_+`.
So, in this case, the `Int` class has this method as shown in the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Int.html).
But yes, as said @Tim it is a common behaviour in mainstream programming languages :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer makes sense. `+y` is equivalent to a function call of `+(y)` (though it's an operation). In this case if you did `-y` it would give an answer of `-20`, which is again correct.

This is very typical for most programming languages.